# Could not determine the dependencies of task -testone

Tags: java, gradle

I started learning Gradle (Java + Gradle) and created this very basic - build.gralde - file.

```
task testone(type: Test) {
    println ("Started TestSetUp")
}
```

In Console when ran command -> gradlew testone -- intellij is throwing error:

```
> Configure project :
Started TestSetUp

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':testone'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you’re using a JVM language plugin — such as the Java Plugin —
> you will automatically get the following:
>
> A dedicated test source set for unit tests
>
> A test task of type Test that runs those unit tests

In "build.gradle", after adding java plugin, the task ran successfully.

```
plugins {
    id 'java' 
}
task testone(type: Test) {
    println ("Task of type Test Success")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i can help you with that , By changing the type from Test to Copy , this will build perfectly , Copy is a defined type in gradle and running `gradle testone -q` will show your output .

I think the problem is with your defined type , by declaring the type as `Test` you need to add more configuration for this , because the error i got when i tried to register the task like

```
tasks.register testone(type: Test) {
    println ("Started TestSetUp")
}
```

was `Could not find method testone() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test}` so your issue is with the Test type , i spose your missing some extra configuration .